# Printing the lines horizontally in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Query :

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region us-east-1 | 
    grep -w "VpcId\|CidrBlock" | 
        cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d '[','"',',','{',' '
```

Raw Output before sorting :

```
[
    {
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxxx",
        "CidrBlock": "1.0.0.0/16",
    "OwnerId": "1234567890"
    }
]
[
    {
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxxx",
        "CidrBlock": "2.0.0.0/16",
    "OwnerId": "1234567890"
    }
]
```

Outputafter sorting :

```
vpc-xxxxxx
1.0.0.0/16
1234567890
vpc-xxxxxx
2.0.0.0/16
1234567890
```

I wanted the output in this format

```
vpc-xxxxxx|1.0.0.0|1234567890 
vpc-xxxxxx|2.0.0.0|1234567890
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Can you add sample output of `aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region us-east-1 | grep -w "VpcId|CidrBlock"`?

Comment: paste is your friend. I can't see how you want three columns from each two lines. However, `paste -s -d '|' - - -` is a starting point for the man page.

Comment: Hi JANN,
```
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxx",
                    "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.x4",
            "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxx",
                    "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
            "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxx",
                    "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
           "CidrBlock": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

Comment: Hi Paul,

I wanted it in this format  " vpc-xxxxxx | 1.0.0.0"

next line 

"vpc-xxxxxx | 2.0.0.0 " 

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: @arunkumar please [edit] your question to add extra information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. So please [edit] and add the output. The output you show has no `VpcId` and no `CidrBlock` so we can't understand what you need. Also, pelase show us the actual output you expect from the example input. You say you want "VPC ID | CIDR Block | Region" but what are these things? How can we identify them?

Comment: So you want us to add a `"` followed by two spaces to the beginning of each line and a space followed by a `"` to the end? If not, please make sure your output is actually what you need.

Comment: @terdon i have updated the query ... I need it without the quotes

Comment: But you do want the extra spaces?

Comment: vpc-xxxxxx | 1.0.0.0   .. no spaces needed

Comment: There are spaces in that output. Are they needed?

Comment: no  @kusalananda ..just pipe will do

Comment: You recent edit invalidates my answer, so I deleted it. It would be better if you could just show us the output of the `aws` command so that we don't have to second guess what your data is or can be.

Comment: That "raw output" is not valid JSON. It seems to be missing a comma between the two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use query from aws, then `awk` (and a bit of `tr`)

```
 aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region us-east-1 --query 'Vpcs[].{VpcId: VpcId, CidrBlock: CidrBlock}'|
  tr -d '",' |
  awk -F: '$1 ~/VpcId/  { vpc=$2 } $1 ~ /CidrBlock/ { printf "%s | %s\n",vpc,$2 } '
```

which give (for me)

```
vpc-d98685b3 |  172.31.0.0/16
```

from raw output

```
[
    {
        "VpcId": "vpc-d98685b3",
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks this helped.... one more thing ... I need to pass my act ID and the region along with it .. is that possible ? 

---
for r in `cat regions.txt`;do aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region $r --query 'Vpcs[].{VpcId: VpcId, CidrBlock: CidrBlock}'|   tr -d '",' |   awk -F: '$1 ~/VpcId/  { vpc=$2 } $1 ~ /CidrBlock/ { printf "%s | %s\n",vpc,$2 } ';echo $ACC_ID $r;done
---

want to append :  $ACC_ID and $r  on each run inside the loop to map the vpc with acc id and the region

Comment: @arunkumar Your follow up question is, well, a follow up question. Consider asking it as a separate question instead of posting unintelligible code in a comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have modified the query now.. can you help me with it ?

Comment: @arunkumar No, you should ask that as a separate question. You have already accepted an answer to your original question and we only allow one issue per question.

Comment: @Kusalananda https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592478/passing-variables-in-the-for-loop-and-to-get-it-appended-to-the-output

can you answer it now ?

Comment: @Archemar ... I have added Owner ID as well, can you let me know to add that as well in the AWK command ?